# Replace more than one line break (\n) in a cell from a range

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have this script that replaces line breaks for a comma and space and triggered by edit event. However, it only replaces one line break per edit event. My sheet is populated by a form (not Google Forms) and in three columns I always receive up to four line breaks in cells of columns M, N and O (result of a multiple-choice fields in the form).

```
function testReplaceInSheet(){
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
var range = sheet.getRange("M2:O"); 
replaceInSheet(sheet,'values','test');
}    

function replaceInSheet(sheet, to_replace, replace_with) {    

//get the current data range values as an array
var values = sheet.getRange("M2:O").getValues();
//loop over the rows in the array
for(var row in values){

//use Array.map to execute a replace call on each of the cells in the row.
var replaced_values = values[row].map(function(original_value){
  return original_value.toString().replace("\n",", ");
});

//replace the original row values with the replaced values
values[row] = replaced_values;
}
//write the updated values to the sheet
sheet.getRange("M2:O").setValues(values);
}
```

With this code I have to edit my sheet every time I need to remove a line break so it only replaces one line break at a time. How do I replace this:
COLUMN M, N, O:

```
word1
word2
word3
word4
```

into this:

```
word1, word2, word3, word4
```

without having to edit my sheet three times?

I already set the trigger in three ways: "on edit", "on change", and "on form submission" but that does not remove all line breaks after form submission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pnuts already pointed out the solution; use global flag "g" for global string replacement, `replace(/\n/g, ",")`.

Your script also has a side effect of converting everything to strings. What if the user entered a number or a date? I would do

```
return (original_value.replace ? original_value.replace(/\n/g, ",") : original_value);
```

This performs the replacement if it makes sense (on data types that have `.replace` method, i.e., strings) and otherwise leaves data unchanged.

Also, consider using [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events) which allow triggered scripts to act only on the range that was actually modified, instead of the entire data set. As is, your script re-runs over the old cells repeatedly. Along these lines, refocus the script on *range*  instead of *sheet* as follows:

```
function triggeredFunction(e) {
  var range = e.range;  // or var range = sheet.getRange("M2:O") if not using event object
  replaceInRange(range, 'values', 'test');
}  

function replaceInRange(range, to_replace, replace_with) {    
   var values = range.getValues();
   newValues = values.map(function(row) {
     return row.map(function(originalValue) {
       return (originalValue.replace ? originalValue.replace(/\n/g, ",") : originalValue);
     });
   });
   range.setValues(newValues);
}
```

This is cleaner in several ways:

- The edited range is not hardcoded in the replacing function, it's received as a parameter.
- Even if the edited range is hardcoded in `triggeredFunction`, that's only one place where "M2:O" appears. So if the columns change, only one line of code will need a revision.
- The array iteration is consistently `.map` instead of a mix of `map` and for-loop.
- camelCase is used consistently

Comment: Your first suggestion worked like a charm Michelle!!! Thanks so much!

your second suggestion gives me error: 
    TypeError: Cannot read property "range" from undefined. (line 2, file "linebreak")

Comment: That's because the function doesn't get the event object unless it was launched by a trigger. If you try to run "triggeredFunction" manually, e is undefined so it won't work.